# Updating cache on update of database table

Tags: caching, appfabric, sql-update

I am using AppFabric to handle the caching capabilities of my website. I would like the
products cache to be updated once there has been a change within the products table
within my database. I read about implementing a read-through but from reading about I 
found:

```
Read: Called when a cache client requests a cached item that does not currently exist in the associated cache.
```

This doesn't seem like it will solve my problem as I'd like the products cache to be
updated once a change to the table has been discovered, it won't necessarily not exist
in the cache in the first place. Is there any way I can do this using AppFabric 
capabilities?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you just want to have a SqlCacheDependency mechanism. In the past, it was very usefull for In Memory Cache.

However, there is no support within AppFabric caching for the SqlCacheDependency mechanism (or in fact for any kind of dependency). You have to build your own ...

In addition, With a read-through provider, the cache detects the missing item and calls the provider to perform the data load. If your add your item with an expiration of 30 minutes, the provider will never not try to reload it before its expiration.

Eventually, you can try to update the cache with a Write-Behind provider. It will update periodically you database.

Comment: The write behind does not update the cache. The write behind updates your data store according to updates to the cache.
The read through detects the missing cache item if it is not there in the first place. This is my problem.

Comment: yes, but working with a distributed cache implies working with stale data. Use a provider or not allow you to choose where stale data will be located : on the cache (due to data item expiration) or in the database (because provider will persit you data periodically). Design WebFarms and IS is a bit different from a  classic vertical web site (webserver + DB)